# Need to show login details in jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Im making a desktop application in java and i need some help ,

Im using sql database to store all my information on the users , e.g UserName , Password , full name .
i have 2 frames , The first one is the login frame where the admin enters his username and password and if it matches with the details on sql database then it will take him to the next frame which is the admin panel , now i want that the admins full name should show on the top left corner of the second frame(which is the admin panel) in the NorthPanel,
this is my codes for both frames , please help

How do i take the name of the admin that logged in from the sql database and show it in the admin panel?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
    import java.awt.event.*;
     import java.sql.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*  

public class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener, FocusListener,       WindowListener
{
JPanel UserPanel,NorthPanel;

JLabel UserId,UserPassword;
JLabel LblFrgtPass;

JTextField TxtUser;

JPasswordField TxtUserPass;

JButton BtnLogin;

Connection con=null;
Statement stmt=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
boolean flag=false;


public Login()
{
    add(GetUserPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(GetNorthPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    addWindowListener(this);
}

public boolean GetConnection()
{
    flag=false;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Project");
        stmt=con.createStatement();
        flag=true;
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        flag=false;
    }
    return flag;
}

public boolean CloseConnection()
{
    flag=false;
    try
    {
        if(con!=null)
        {
            con.close();
            flag=true;
        }
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        flag=false;
    }
    return flag;
}

public ResultSet GetRecords(String sql)
{
    rs=null;
    try
    {
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        rs=null;
    }
    return rs;
}


JPanel GetNorthPanel()
{
    NorthPanel = new JPanel();
    NorthPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    ImageIcon titleIcon = new ImageIcon("titleicon.png");
    JLabel title = new JLabel(titleIcon);

    NorthPanel.add(title);

    NorthPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    return NorthPanel;
}

JLabel GetLblForgetPassword()
{
    LblFrgtPass = new JLabel("Forgot Password ? ");
    return LblFrgtPass;
}


JPanel GetUserPanel()
{
    UserPanel=new JPanel();
    UserPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    UserPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



    GridBagConstraints GbcUserId = new GridBagConstraints();
    GbcUserId.gridx=1;
    GbcUserId.gridy=3;
    GbcUserId.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    GbcUserId.insets = new Insets(10, 70, 0, 0);
    UserPanel.add(GetUserId(),GbcUserId);



    GridBagConstraints GbcTxtUser = new GridBagConstraints();
    GbcTxtUser.gridx=2;
    GbcTxtUser.gridy=3;

    GbcTxtUser.insets = new Insets(10, 40, 0, 0);
    UserPanel.add(GetTxtUser(),GbcTxtUser);



    GridBagConstraints GbcUserPassword = new GridBagConstraints();
    GbcUserPassword.gridx=1;
    GbcUserPassword.gridy=4;
    GbcUserPassword.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    GbcUserPassword.insets = new Insets(10, 70, 0, 0);
    UserPanel.add(GetUserPassword(),GbcUserPassword);




    GridBagConstraints GbcTxtUserPass = new GridBagConstraints();
    GbcTxtUserPass.gridx=2;
    GbcTxtUserPass.gridy=4;

    GbcTxtUserPass.insets = new Insets(10, 40, 0, 0);
    UserPanel.add(GetTxtUserPass(),GbcTxtUserPass);




    GridBagConstraints GbcBtnLogin = new GridBagConstraints();
    GbcBtnLogin.gridx=2;
    GbcBtnLogin.gridy=5;

    GbcBtnLogin.insets = new Insets(50, 50, 20, 20);
    UserPanel.add(GetBtnLogin(),GbcBtnLogin);

    GridBagConstraints GbcLblFrgtPass = new GridBagConstraints();
    GbcLblFrgtPass.gridx=3;
    GbcLblFrgtPass.gridy=5;

    GbcLblFrgtPass.insets = new Insets(50, 0, 20, 20);
    UserPanel.add(GetLblFrgtPass(),GbcLblFrgtPass);



    return UserPanel;
}

JLabel GetUserId()
{
    UserId = new JLabel("User Id       :      ");
    UserId.setFont(new Font("Bookman Old Style", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    return UserId;
}

JTextField GetTxtUser()
{
    TxtUser = new JTextField(10);
    TxtUser.addKeyListener(this);
    TxtUser.addFocusListener(this);
    return TxtUser;
}

JLabel GetUserPassword()
{
    UserPassword = new JLabel("Password   :      ");
    UserPassword.setFont(new Font("Bookman Old Style", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    return UserPassword;
}

JPasswordField GetTxtUserPass()
{
    TxtUserPass = new JPasswordField(10);
    TxtUserPass.addKeyListener(this);
    TxtUserPass.addFocusListener(this);
    return TxtUserPass;
}

JLabel GetLblFrgtPass()
{
    LblFrgtPass = new JLabel("Forgot Passord ?");
    return LblFrgtPass;
}

JButton GetBtnLogin()
{
    BtnLogin = new JButton("  LogIn  ");
    //Project1 p = new Project1();
    BtnLogin.addActionListener(this);
    BtnLogin.setFont(new Font("Bookman Old Style", Font.PLAIN, 14));

    BtnLogin.registerKeyboardAction(BtnLogin.getActionForKeyStroke(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false)),
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, false),
            JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);

    BtnLogin.registerKeyboardAction(BtnLogin.getActionForKeyStroke(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true)),
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, true),
            JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);

    return BtnLogin;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==BtnLogin)
    {
        String User_Id = TxtUser.getText().trim();
        String User_Pass = TxtUserPass.getText().trim();

        String sql = "Select * from users where UserId = '"+User_Id+"' and Password= '"+User_Pass+"'";

        if(GetConnection()==true)
        {
                        try
                        {
                            rs =GetRecords(sql);
                int count = 0;
            String usertype="";

            while(rs.next())
            {
                                count = count + 1;
                                usertype=rs.getString(3);
            }

            if(count ==1)
            {
                                if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("student"))
                                {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student Frame");
                                }
                                else if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("teacher"))
                                {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Teacher Frame");
                                }
                               else if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("admin"))
                                {
                                                            Admin frame=new Admin();
                                                            frame.setSize(600, 400);
                                                            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                                                            frame.setVisible(true);

                                }
                                dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Not Found!");
            }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //ex.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println("ERROR2");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not Connected");
        }
    }


}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ex)
{
    //ASCII :American Standard Code for Information Interchange

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.getKeyCode());
    if(ex.getKeyCode()==10 && ex.getSource()==TxtUser)
    {
        TxtUserPass.requestFocus();
    }
    else if(ex.getKeyCode()==10 && ex.getSource()==TxtUserPass)
    {
        BtnLogin.requestFocus();
    }
    else if(ex.getKeyCode()==10 && ex.getSource()==BtnLogin)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Not Found!");
    }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ex)
{
    if(ex.getKeyCode()==10 && ex.getSource()==TxtUserPass)
    {
    //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Not Found!");
    }   
}

public void focusGained(FocusEvent ex)
{
    if(ex.getSource()==TxtUser)
    {
        TxtUser.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
    else if(ex.getSource()==TxtUserPass)
    {
        TxtUserPass.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
}

public void focusLost(FocusEvent ex)
{
    if(ex.getSource()==TxtUser)
    {
        TxtUser.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
    else if(ex.getSource()==TxtUserPass)
    {
        TxtUserPass.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
}

public void windowActivated(WindowEvent ex)
{
}
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent ex)
{
}
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent ex)
{
}
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent ex)
{
}
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ex)
{
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"GoodBye","Exit LogIn",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent ex)
{

}
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent ex)
{
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{

                    Login Frame = new Login();
                    Frame.setResizable(false);
                    Frame.setSize(600,400);
                    Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    Frame.setVisible(true);
            Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

The code below is the second frame

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.sql.*;
 public class Admin extends Login {

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Admin");
JPanel panel;
JPanel nPanel;
JLabel logOut;
JLabel UserName;

JButton btn1;
JButton btn2;
JButton btn3;
JButton btn4;
JButton btn5;
JButton btn6;

private Connection con = null;
private Statement stmt = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
boolean flag = false;

//****************MAIN CONSTRUCTOR******************************************
public Admin(){

    add(GetNPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(GetCPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);



}

//****************SQL CONNECTION********************************************

public boolean GetConnection(){
    flag = false;

    try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Project");
        //System.out.println("Connected");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        flag=true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        flag = false;
    }

    return flag;
}

//****************CENTER PANEL**********************************************
JPanel GetCPanel(){

    panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    //gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);  //cell padding
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; //fill cell area
            gbc.weightx = 1;  // fill horizontal cell area
            gbc.weighty = 1;  //fill vertical cell area

            //btn1
            btn1 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("teacher.png"));
            btn1.setToolTipText("Add / Edit / Remove Teachers");
            gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(btn1, gbc);

            //btn2
            btn2 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("student.png"));
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(btn2, gbc);

            //btn3
            btn3 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("notice.png"));
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(btn3, gbc);

            //btn4
            btn4 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("complaints.png"));
            gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(btn4, gbc);

            //btn5
            btn5 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("messages.png"));
            gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(btn5, gbc);

            //btn6
            btn6 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("password.png"));
            gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(btn6, gbc);

            return panel;
}

JPanel GetNPanel()
{
    nPanel = new JPanel();  
    return nPanel;
}



//****************NORTH PANEL***********************************************

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Admin();


    Admin frame = new Admin();
    //FRAME
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);

}

}
```

Comment: the answer to this would be to set the name to a JLabel and add it to northpanel. Somehow i think it's not the answer you're looking for. can you rephrase the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending your `AdminPanel` Frame from `Login` frame. What you can do is create an instance variable in your `Login` frame and store the value of Full Name of user to it if the login is successful.

As the `AdminPanel` inherits `Login` Frame, so it will automatically get the value of Full name of user. Then you can take any JLabel in your AdminPanel in the left corner and set text the value of instance variable there.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a setName method that takes a string variable and then set the text of the label.

```
Public void setName(String name){
Label.setText(name)
}
```

Then I would call the method upon the login being successful.